# Blender adds an end joint to any child joint automatically

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I am facing an issue with blender armature, I have created a skeleton that consists of a parent joint and a number of child joints, when I export it with fbx file and then reimport it to blender I see blender have added an extra joint to the end of any child joint automatically.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89975/blender-adds-extra-bones-to-ends-of-armature-when-i-export-as-fbx-or-obj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blender doesn't add joints, it adds bones, precisely because Blender doesn't work with joints.

Bones are made of a head and a tail, joints are just one point.
When Blender export its bone system to other formats who use joints, it cannot accurately represent the armature as is, because joints are just unique points unlike Blender's bones, every Blender bone will be represented as a joint using the bone's head coordinates. So, in order to preserve the armature look in a joint system, Blender optionally adds bones where there's a naked bone tail, so that in any joint-based program it looks like in Blender.

But in Blender, that will look just like a bunch of new bones. It's nothing harmful on the functionality side, just uglier and messy. If you don't want it, you can disable the leaf bones either during export or import.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate that; I am a new user of blender I have come from maya so messing up these names is my daily routine. anyway, thank you I was worried if it makes problem when they exported to unreal engine.

Comment: They shouldn't cause any issue. You might appreciate to export without leaf bones just to have a rig visually more pleasing in Unreal, and maybe have slightly lighter asset files, but that's about it.